# How to change data after success URLs sent to partner API's if they can only be GET requests?

Tags: api-design, web-api, http, http-request

A lot of times there's a parameter in a partner API endpoint like `success_url` where you provide the partner API with an endpoint on your internal API to redirect the client.

For example, on Stripe you can create a [checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) using `POST /v1/checkout/sessions`. In the body you send Stripe a [`success_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-success_url). You redirect the client to Stripe where they make their payment. After they complete their payment successfully, Stripe will redirect the client to that `success_url` you included.

Since you are only sending a URL aren't all of these requests only GET requests? And if so, a GET is defined in the HTTP protocol as idempotent and safe. So I couldn't use this request to make [changes to data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server) on my server. But after a successful purchase, I will want to make changes like updating or creating an `Order` on my server, updating stock left for the `Item`, etc.

How can I make changes after these success, refresh, return, or cancel URL's if they are all GET requests?

Comment: You will not make changes with the GET requests, but you will know how to proceed with them. Then you can make the necessary changes to the data on your server depending on what the response is.

Comment: Ok that makes sense